# Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/simple

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

This error shows when I try to run a vue init webpack command.

vue-cli · Failed to download repo vuejs-templates/simple: unable to verify the first certificate

Pls help! I want to proceed and learn vue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try to clone the git repo and then initiate project offline

```
git clone https://github.com/vuejs-templates/simple ~/.vue-templates/simple
vue init simple my-project --offline
cd my-project
npm install
npm run dev
```

credits https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/258#issuecomment-325021153

Comment: Hi @Bogdan Matkovsky, where can i find the .vue-templates folder in my local machine?

Comment: In "~/.vue-templates/simple" the ~ sign means your user's home folder. So .vue-templates is in your home folder

Comment: I'm using windows 7, where can I find it exactly? @Bogdan Matkovsky

Comment: On Windows machine the ~ shortcut might not work. Then try the first command from your user home folder as "git clone https://github.com/vuejs-templates/simple .vue-templates/simple". This should create the .vue-templates folder and clone simple template into that folder

Comment: Your home folder may be something like C:/Users/Home or C:/{yourUserName}/Home etc.

Comment: if it doesn't help show the output of "vue init simple my-project --offline" command

Comment: C:\Users\IT\Desktop\vue sample>vue init webpack appvue01 --offline
> Use cached template at ~\.vue-templates\webpack

? Target directory exists. Continue? Yes
   vue-cli · Local template "C:\Users\IT\.vue-templates\webpack" not found.

Comment: Looking at the output from vue init on a Windows platform(vue cli 3.0.0-beta.9), seems like that is a legacy API.  

The following seems to be the right approach:
vue-init simple my-project --offline

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack.git ~/.vue-templates/simple` is better working for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem here seems to be the environment where you are tying to  download the template, Are you through a proxy?. One solution is forking the template you want, and then init vue in that template, but i can't tell if this works for all cases.

Fork the desired template, in your case webpack from https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

And then just init it by using `vue init yourGithubUsername/webpack`

Comment: it's almost working, but in Generate project in current directory? Yes, the error "unable to verify the first certificate" appears.

Answer (score 0):

Someone encountered the same problem as yours, referencing on this [issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/483), it is very likely you are behind VPN, try running this instead:

```
npm config set npm_config_strict_ssl=false
vue init webpack my-project
```

Comment: it says 'npm_config_strict_ssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What is your `npm` version? (run `npm --v`)

Comment: my npm version is 5.6.0